# How do I add the appropriate parentheses " '(' or ')' " to the JavaScript calculator display screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

This is the button I have created for the parentheses.

```
 <div class="col">
          <button class="parentheses rounded-pill  btn-outline-primary btn btn-lg" id="keyButton" data-key="operator">()</button>
</div>
```

I am trying to only show "(" if there is not a number on the calculator display. If there is a number on the calculator display I want to add ")" to the calculator display.

This is the JavaScript code.

```
for (let i = 0; i < keyButton.length; i++) {    // Loops through keyButton to get values
  
  // console.log(keyButton[i].textContent);    // and console.log all keyButton values
  
   keyButton[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
     
    // console.log(keyButton[i].textContent);
     
      if (mathOperators.includes(keyButton[i].textContent)){
        console.log('operator');
      }
      if (keyNumbers.includes(keyButton[i].textContent)) {
        console.log('number');
      }
      if (keyButton[i].textContent === '=') {
        count = eval(assigned);
      }
      if (keyButton[i].textContent === 'C') {
        // clear entire screen
      }
      if (keyButton[i].textContent === '<-') {
        // clear one value
      }
      if (keyButton[i].textContent === '(') {
        console.log("(")
      } else
      if (keyButton[i].textContent !== "(") {
        console.log(")")
      }
      
      
     updateScreen(keyButton[i].textContent);
   });
  
}


function updateScreen (kb) {
  
    displayNum.textContent = assigned+=kb;   // Displays the current number on the calculator
    answer.textContent = count;
    backspace.removeAttribute('disabled');
  
}

const mathOperators = ['+', '*', '/', '-', '=', 'C', '+/-', '%', '()', '(-', '.', '<-'];
```

When I tested it, it only gives me "()" everytime I press the button, instead of "(" or ")".

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle of working code

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? Where is the code that is supposed to add `)`?

Comment: Here is a working JSFiddle code.. https://jsfiddle.net/acroucamp/w6jskhLv/1/

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed what you wanted. when the button `()` is clicked you will get `(` or `)` based on the display value.

```js
const displayNum = document.querySelector('.displayValue');
const keyButton = document.querySelectorAll('#keyButton');
const backspace = document.querySelector('.backSpace');
const answer = document.querySelector('.autoUpdatedAnswer');

// Variable lib
let count = "",
  result, assigned = "",
  operator = "";
const mathOperators = ['+', '*', '/', '-', '=', 'C', '+/-', '%', '()', '(-', '.', '<-'];
const keyNumbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'];


for (let i = 0; i < keyButton.length; i++) { // Loops through keyButton to get values

  // console.log(keyButton[i].textContent);    // and console.log all keyButton values

  keyButton[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    // console.log(keyButton[i].textContent);
        var keyboardValue = keyButton[i].textContent;
    if (mathOperators.includes(keyButton[i].textContent)) {
      console.log('operator');
    }
    if (keyNumbers.includes(keyButton[i].textContent)) {
      console.log('number');
    }
    if (keyButton[i].textContent === '=') {
      count = eval(assigned);
    }
    if (keyButton[i].textContent === 'C') {
      // clear entire screen
    }
    if (keyButton[i].textContent === '<-') {
      // clear one value
    }
    if (keyButton[i].textContent === '(') {
      console.log("(")
    } else
    if (keyButton[i].textContent !== "(") {
      console.log(")")
    }

        if (keyboardValue === '()') {
            if (/\w*\d{1,}\w*/g.test(assigned)) {
        keyboardValue = ')'
      } else {
            keyboardValue = '('
        }
            
        }


    updateScreen(keyboardValue);
  });

}


function updateScreen(kb) {
    
  displayNum.textContent = assigned += kb; // Displays the current number on the calculator
  answer.textContent = count;
  backspace.removeAttribute('disabled');

}
```

```css
.screen {
  text-align: right;
}

.c1, .c2 {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#keys {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #6495ED;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <title>JavaScript Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    

    <div class="container c1 mt-5 w-50 border-bottom p-5 rounded-top">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="screen">
            <h1 class="displayValue">0</h1>
            <h2 class="autoUpdatedAnswer"></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button class="backSpace rounded-pill btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" id="keyButton" data-key="operator" disabled value="backspace"><-</button>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container c2 w-50 rounded-bottom" style="height: 400px; text-align: center;" id="keys">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button class="clear rounded-pill  btn btn-danger btn-lg" id="keyButton" data-key="operator" >C</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="parentheses rounded-pill  btn-outline-primary btn btn-lg" id="keyButton" data-key="operator">()</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="percent rounded-pill  btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" id="keyButton" data-key="operator">%</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="division rounded-pill  btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" id="keyButton" data-key="operator">/</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">  
        <div class="col">
          <button class="seven rounded-pill  btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="keyButton">7</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="eight rounded-pill btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="keyButton">8</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="nine rounded-pill  btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="keyButton">9</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="multiply rounded-pill  btn-outline-primary btn btn-lg" id="keyButton" data-key="operator">*</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button class="four rounded-pill  btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="keyButton">4</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="five rounded-pill  btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="keyButton">5</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="six rounded-pill  btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="keyButton">6</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="subtract rounded-pill  btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" id="keyButton" data-key="operator">-</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button class="one rounded-pill  btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="keyButton">1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="two rounded-pill  btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="keyButton">2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="three rounded-pill  btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="keyButton">3</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="addition rounded-pill  btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" id="keyButton" data-key="operator">+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button class="plusNegative rounded-pill  btn-secondary btn btn-lg" id="keyButton" data-key="operator">+/-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="zero rounded-pill  btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="keyButton">0</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="decimal rounded-pill  btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="keyButton" data-key="operator">.</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button class="equal rounded-pill  btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="keyButton" data-key="operator">=</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```